# No access to my data in the callback function of d3.csv() method

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

The callback function `draw`seems not to have any access to the data inside the callback provided to `d3.csv()`. In the callback `console.log` prints:

> data: null

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Correlation XX</title>
    <script src="d3v4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function draw(data) {
        console.log("data: " + data); // <-- talking about this line
        var width = 860,
            height = 500;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width)
                  .attr("height", height)
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      d3.csv("modified_data_titanic.csv", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.Age = +d.Age;
          d.Survived = +d.Survived;
        });
      }, draw);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The csv-data:

```
"","PassengerId","Survived","Pclass","Name","Sex","Age","SibSp","Parch","Ticket","Fare","Cabin","Embarked","Child","Survived_new","Category"
"1",1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris","male",22,1,0,"A/5 21171",7.25,"","S","FALSE",0,"20-29 m"
"2",2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)","female",38,1,0,"PC 17599",71.2833,"C85","C","FALSE",0,"30-39 f"
"3",3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina","female",26,0,0,"STON/O2. 3101282",7.925,"","S","FALSE",0,"20-29 f"
"4",4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)","female",35,1,0,"113803",53.1,"C123","S","FALSE",0,"30-39 f"
"5",5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry","male",35,0,0,"373450",8.05,"","S","FALSE",0,"30-39 m"
"6",6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James","male",NA,0,0,"330877",8.4583,"","Q",NA,0,NA
"7",7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J","male",54,0,0,"17463",51.8625,"E46","S","FALSE",0,"50-59 m"
"8",8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard","male",2,3,1,"349909",21.075,"","S","TRUE",0,"0-9 m"
"9",9,1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)","female",27,0,2,"347742",11.1333,"","S","FALSE",0,"20-29 f"
"10",10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)","female",14,1,0,"237736",30.0708,"","C","TRUE",0,"10-19 f"
"11",11,1,3,"Sandstrom, Miss. Marguerite Rut","female",4,1,1,"PP 9549",16.7,"G6","S","TRUE",0,"0-9 f"
"12",12,1,1,"Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth","female",58,0,0,"113783",26.55,"C103","S","FALSE",0,"50-59 f"
"13",13,0,3,"Saundercock, Mr. William Henry","male",20,0,0,"A/5. 2151",8.05,"","S","FALSE",0,"20-29 m"
```

Background info: My actual **goal** is to use a column like *Age* or *Survived* as the range for the x-axis.

Comment: Return the data after your forEach. `data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.Age = +d.Age;
          d.Survived = +d.Survived;
        }); return data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row conversion function, i.e. the second parameter to `d3.csv()`, is not correct. Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse) for details:

> If a *row* conversion function is specified, the specified function is invoked for each row, being passed an object representing the current row (`d`), the index (`i`) starting at zero for the first non-header row, and the array of column names. If the returned value is null or undefined, the row is skipped and will be ommitted from the array returned by *dsv*.parse; otherwise, the returned value defines the corresponding row object.

There are two issues:

1. The function is called for every row, not for the entire data like your function is supposed to be called.
2. As noted by Adrian in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971900/d3-js-no-access-to-my-data-in-the-callback-function-of-the-csv-method#comment69153093_40971900) you need to return the value for the row; otherwise, the row will be skipped.

The following function should do the trick:

```
d3.csv("modified_data_titanic.csv", function(d) {  // in this case d is one row
  d.Age = +d.Age;
  d.Survived = +d.Survived;
  return d;
}, draw);
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I used ```forEach``` because of this article: http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html

Comment: If you re-read the article, you will notice there are two approaches to this. The first snippet calls `d3.csv()` with **two** parameters, where no conversion function is supplied. The second argument is optional! In the callback `data` will then hold the full array of parse rows. this can be iterated over using `.forEach()`. However, the second snippet a few paragraphs further down does provide a conversion function, i.e. it is supplied **three** parameters, like in your question. Which way to choose depends largely on your need to pre-process vs post-process your data.

Answer (score 1):

Your accessor (or row) function is not correct.

For start, the accessor function doesn't need a `forEach`. Besides that, you have to return each row. All together, these are the changes:

```
d3.csv("modified_data_titanic.csv", function(d) {
     d.Age = +d.Age;
     d.Survived = +d.Survived;
     return d;
 }, draw);
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I used ```forEach``` because of this article: http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html